# Defining AdditiveGroup with alga crate

Tags: rust

According to the  [alga documentation](https://docs.rs/alga_derive/0.7.1/alga_derive/), the macros (defined in alga_traits):

```
#[derive(Alga)]
#[alga_traits(Group(Additive))]
struct TrivialGroup;
```

can be used to implement the `AbstractGroup` marker trait with `Additive` operator, if implementations of the traits `Identity`, `PartialEq`, `Inverse` and `AbstractMagma` are provided.

However, if I implement them as:

```
use alga::general::{AbstractMagma, Additive, AdditiveGroup, Identity, Inverse}; // 0.7.2
use alga_derive::Alga; // 0.7.1

#[derive(Alga, Clone, Copy, PartialEq, Debug)]
#[alga_traits(Group(Additive))]
pub struct TrivialGroup;

impl AbstractMagma<Additive> for TrivialGroup {
    fn operate(&self, _right: &Self) -> Self {
        TrivialGroup {}
    }
}

impl Identity<Additive> for TrivialGroup {
    fn identity() -> Self {
        TrivialGroup {}
    }
}

impl Inverse<Additive> for TrivialGroup {
    fn inverse(&self) -> Self {
        TrivialGroup {}
    }
}

struct Bar<T: AdditiveGroup> {
    t: T,
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Bar::<TrivialGroup> { t: TrivialGroup {} };
}
```

The compiler still doesn't think that `TrivialGroup` satisfies the `AdditiveGroup` trait:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `TrivialGroup: num_traits::identities::Zero` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:31:15
   |
31 |     let foo = Bar::<TrivialGroup> { t: TrivialGroup {} };
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `num_traits::identities::Zero` is not implemented for `TrivialGroup`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `_ALGA_DERIVE_TrivialGroup::_alga::general::AdditiveLoop` for `TrivialGroup`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `_ALGA_DERIVE_TrivialGroup::_alga::general::AdditiveGroup` for `TrivialGroup`
note: required by `Bar`
  --> src/main.rs:26:1
   |
26 | struct Bar<T: AdditiveGroup> {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0277]: the trait bound `TrivialGroup: std::ops::Neg` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:31:15
   |
31 |     let foo = Bar::<TrivialGroup> { t: TrivialGroup {} };
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::ops::Neg` is not implemented for `TrivialGroup`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `_ALGA_DERIVE_TrivialGroup::_alga::general::ClosedNeg` for `TrivialGroup`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `_ALGA_DERIVE_TrivialGroup::_alga::general::AdditiveLoop` for `TrivialGroup`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `_ALGA_DERIVE_TrivialGroup::_alga::general::AdditiveGroup` for `TrivialGroup`
note: required by `Bar`
  --> src/main.rs:26:1
   |
26 | struct Bar<T: AdditiveGroup> {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0277]: cannot subtract `TrivialGroup` from `TrivialGroup`
  --> src/main.rs:31:15
   |
31 |     let foo = Bar::<TrivialGroup> { t: TrivialGroup {} };
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no implementation for `TrivialGroup - TrivialGroup`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::ops::Sub` is not implemented for `TrivialGroup`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `_ALGA_DERIVE_TrivialGroup::_alga::general::ClosedSub` for `TrivialGroup`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `_ALGA_DERIVE_TrivialGroup::_alga::general::AdditiveQuasigroup` for `TrivialGroup`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `_ALGA_DERIVE_TrivialGroup::_alga::general::AdditiveLoop` for `TrivialGroup`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `_ALGA_DERIVE_TrivialGroup::_alga::general::AdditiveGroup` for `TrivialGroup`
note: required by `Bar`
  --> src/main.rs:26:1
   |
26 | struct Bar<T: AdditiveGroup> {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0277]: cannot subtract-assign `TrivialGroup` from `TrivialGroup`
  --> src/main.rs:31:15
   |
31 |     let foo = Bar::<TrivialGroup> { t: TrivialGroup {} };
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no implementation for `TrivialGroup -= TrivialGroup`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::ops::SubAssign` is not implemented for `TrivialGroup`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `_ALGA_DERIVE_TrivialGroup::_alga::general::ClosedSub` for `TrivialGroup`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `_ALGA_DERIVE_TrivialGroup::_alga::general::AdditiveQuasigroup` for `TrivialGroup`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `_ALGA_DERIVE_TrivialGroup::_alga::general::AdditiveLoop` for `TrivialGroup`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `_ALGA_DERIVE_TrivialGroup::_alga::general::AdditiveGroup` for `TrivialGroup`
note: required by `Bar`
  --> src/main.rs:26:1
   |
26 | struct Bar<T: AdditiveGroup> {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0277]: cannot add-assign `TrivialGroup` to `TrivialGroup`
  --> src/main.rs:31:15
   |
31 |     let foo = Bar::<TrivialGroup> { t: TrivialGroup {} };
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no implementation for `TrivialGroup += TrivialGroup`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::ops::AddAssign` is not implemented for `TrivialGroup`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `_ALGA_DERIVE_TrivialGroup::_alga::general::ClosedAdd` for `TrivialGroup`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `_ALGA_DERIVE_TrivialGroup::_alga::general::AdditiveSemigroup` for `TrivialGroup`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `_ALGA_DERIVE_TrivialGroup::_alga::general::AdditiveMonoid` for `TrivialGroup`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `_ALGA_DERIVE_TrivialGroup::_alga::general::AdditiveGroup` for `TrivialGroup`
note: required by `Bar`
  --> src/main.rs:26:1
   |
26 | struct Bar<T: AdditiveGroup> {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

How should I define my additive group instead?

Comment: I neither know nor understand alga-derive, but the error message seems to suggest that you need to implement the [`Zero`](https://rust-num.github.io/num/num/trait.Zero.html) trait from the `num` crate.

Comment: I can compile your code fine, without any errors. The only change was to add imports:  `use alga_derive::Alga;` and 
`use alga::general::{AbstractMagma, Additive, Identity, Inverse};`, using version 0.7.1  of both alga and alga_derive.

Comment: Please check your provided code in isolation, to make sure that it can be used to reproduce your problem.

Comment: As my original question stated, the problem was not that the code did not compile, it's that the compiler did not think that `TrivialGroup` satisfied the `AdditiveGroup` trait.  I have added a few lines to turn this failure to satisfy the trait into a self-contained compilation failure.